# Optional JsonPath using Jayway

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

**Question:**

I have a service that takes in a `JSON` string as input. The `JSON` schema is different every time where some fields are not always present. How can I query the values of those fields using Jayway's `JsonPath` when they are present?

**What I've tried:**

I used the `Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL` as Jayway's [readme page](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath) explained

```
Configuration config = Configuration.defaultConfiguration()
    .addOptions(Option.DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL);
if (JsonPath.isPathDefinite(attribute.jsonPath))
{
    String value = JsonPath.using(config).parse(currentTx).read(attribute.jsonPath);
    if (value != null)
    {
        attributeValues.add(value);
    }
}
else
{
    List<String> attributeValuesArray = JsonPath.using(config).parse(currentTx).read(attribute.jsonPath);

    for (String value : attributeValuesArray)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            attributeValues.add(value);
        }
    }
}
```

This should make `JsonPath.read()` return `null` if the path is not found, however my code still throws:

> com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['somepath']

when I give it a inexistent path. Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I realized what I did wrong. The `DEFAULT_PATH_LEAF_TO_NULL` option only takes care of leaf nodes. For example:

Sample Json

```
{
    "foo":{
        "bar":"value"
    }
}
```

If `$.foo.tmp` is queried, JsonPath will return `null` as tmp is suppose to be a leaf node.

If `$.tmp.tmp2` is queried, JsonPath will throw a

> com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException as tmp isn't a leaf and is not present.

In order to bypass this, one should use `Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS`.

Comment: How do we auto-add those paths? is there a way to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `Option.SUPPRESS_EXCEPTIONS` solved my problem which was similar to yours.