# How to update nested fields of Json using scala and Jackson or any other Json framework

Tags: json, scala, jackson, circe, lift-json

I want to edit a nested field of a Json using its path as a string. The path comes from a variable.

```
{
  "Type": "phone",
  "os": "android",
  "Transaction": {
    "Date": {
      Day: "22",
      Month: "Jan"
    },
    "value": "2000"
  }
}
```

I want to update say, Month value Jan to Dec

Comment: Try using any JSON Path library.

Comment: Can you pass me the link to its documentation

Comment: https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: Can you please give a small code example to add a new field called Year to Date: json object with value say 2004

Comment: I don't have much knowledge of scala, In java, I would probably create a class corresponding to json and add the new field there and while converting json to java object, I would write the logic to populate the field.

Comment: I see. But that is not possible as I cannot have a fixed classes since my Json is changing. I need to change the Json string itself. Looking something like put of Jackson

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51971790/1776132