# Transform String into nested Json (Java)

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I would like the guidence from you all, i'm confused in how to go on in a situation at Java + Spring Boot.

I receive from the database 2 columns of strings, the first column is a path separeted by a slash(/) like "crumbs[0]/link/path" and the second column have the value assigned to the first column, and what i'm trying to do is to create a nested JSON with this.

For example, i'm receiving from the database the following response in two columns like a said before:

```
COLUMN 1(PATH), COLUMN 2(VALUE)
"crumbs[0]/link/path", "/pokemon/type/pokemon?lang=en"
"crumbs[0]/link/wid", "tablePokemon",
"crumbs[0]/name", "Pokemon"
"data/records[1]/id", "Pikachu"
"data/records[1]/link/path": "/pokemon/type/eletric/pikachu",
"data/records[1]/link/wid": "tableEletric",
"data/records[1]/available": "true",
"data/records[2]/id", "Bulbasaur"
"data/records[2]/link/path": "/pokemon/type/grass/bulbasaur",
"data/records[2]/link/wid": "tableGrass",
"data/records[2]/available": "true",
```

With this response from database, i'm trying to get this result in Java:

```
"crumbs": [
           {
            "link": {
                 "path": "/pokemon/type/pokemon?lang=en",
                 "wid": "tablePokemon"
            },
            "name": "Pokemon"
           }
],
"data": {
         "records": [
                     {
                      "id": "Pikachu",
                      "link": {
                            "path": "/pokemon/type/eletric/pikachu",
                            "wid": "tableEletric"
                      },
                      "available": "true",
                      },
                      {
                       "id": "Bulbasaur",
                       "link": {
                             "path": "/pokemon/type/grass/bulbasaur",
                             "wid": "tableGrass"
                       },
                       "available": "true",
                       }                    
                    ]
}
```

You guys would have any suggestions for me to achieve this objective?

Thank you all for your time, appreciate any help.

Comment: Plural of Pokemon is Pokemon, just saying.

Comment: `crumbs[0]/link/path` look like XPath which is used with XML and not JSON. What is the reason you insist on using JSON?

Comment: Hi @jurez. Yeah, it looks like XPath that is used with XML, the reason it's that a have to return an API as JSON and i'm having trouble to think how to do it. Any tip it's welcome.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily construct a JSON with com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonPointer!

Some details on parsing a JsonPath and constructing a Json from it is mentioned here [How to add new node to Json using JsonPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51971642/how-to-add-new-node-to-json-using-jsonpath)

You could made use of the code from the above reference to build your code.
Add the com.fasterxml.jackson dependencies to your pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

```java
private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public static void main(String[] args) {
        
/** I'm creating a below map to hold the values you have mentioned in the above case.
 While using JsonPointer I found two issues with the key mentioned here
 1. Key doesnt start with a  / . I'm appending a / with the key while inserting to map 
 2. The arrays in data eg:crumbs[0]/link/path should be represented like crumbs/0/link/path ( I haven't handled this in the code, but it doesn't make much difference in the output)
**/

        Map<String, String> databaseKeyValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
        databaseKeyValues.put("crumbs[0]/link/path", "/pokemon/type/pokemon?lang=en");
        databaseKeyValues.put("crumbs[0]/link/wid", "tablePokemon");
        databaseKeyValues.put("crumbs[0]/name", "Pokemon");
        databaseKeyValues.put("data/records[1]/id", "Pikachu");
        databaseKeyValues.put("data/records[1]/link/path", "/pokemon/type/eletric/pikachu");
        databaseKeyValues.put("data/records[1]/link/wid", "tableEletric");
        databaseKeyValues.put("data/records[1]/available", "true");
        databaseKeyValues.put("data/records[2]/id", "Bulbasaur");
        databaseKeyValues.put("data/records[2]/link/path", "/pokemon/type/grass/bulbasaur");
        databaseKeyValues.put("data/records[2]/link/wid", "tableGrass");
        databaseKeyValues.put("data/records[2]/available", "true");

        ObjectNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
        
        for(java.util.Map.Entry<String, String> e:databaseKeyValues.entrySet()) {
        setJsonPointerValue(rootNode, JsonPointer.compile("/"+e.getKey()), //Adding slash to identify it as the root element, since our source data didn't have proper key!
                new TextNode(e.getValue()));
        }

        try {
            System.out.println(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(rootNode));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void setJsonPointerValue(ObjectNode node, JsonPointer pointer, JsonNode value) {
        JsonPointer parentPointer = pointer.head();
        JsonNode parentNode = node.at(parentPointer);
        String fieldName = pointer.last().toString().substring(1);

        if (parentNode.isMissingNode() || parentNode.isNull()) {
            parentNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
            setJsonPointerValue(node,parentPointer, parentNode); // recursively reconstruct hierarchy
        }

        if (parentNode.isArray()) {
            ArrayNode arrayNode = (ArrayNode) parentNode;
            int index = Integer.valueOf(fieldName);
            // expand array in case index is greater than array size (like JavaScript does)
            for (int i = arrayNode.size(); i <= index; i++) {
                arrayNode.addNull();
            }
            arrayNode.set(index, value);
        } else if (parentNode.isObject()) {
            ((ObjectNode) parentNode).set(fieldName, value);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("`" + fieldName + "` can't be set for parent node `"
                    + parentPointer + "` because parent is not a container but " + parentNode.getNodeType().name());
        }
    }
```

Output:

```json
{
  "data" : {
    "records[1]" : {
      "id" : "Pikachu",
      "link" : {
        "wid" : "tableEletric",
        "path" : "/pokemon/type/eletric/pikachu"
      },
      "available" : "true"
    },
    "records[2]" : {
      "available" : "true",
      "link" : {
        "wid" : "tableGrass",
        "path" : "/pokemon/type/grass/bulbasaur"
      },
      "id" : "Bulbasaur"
    }
  },
  "crumbs[0]" : {
    "link" : {
      "path" : "/pokemon/type/pokemon?lang=en",
      "wid" : "tablePokemon"
    },
    "name" : "Pokemon"
  }
}
```

The json arrays records[1], records[2], crumbs[0] would be sorted out once we handle the JsonPath from crumbs[0]/link/path to crumbs/0/link/path. Just some string operations would help (iterate through the values and replace '[0]' with '/0/', you could write a regex to pattern match and replace!).

Comment: Hi @John Thomas, thank you for all the explanation, this way sound very good to do it!
Just one question, on the line: "ObjectNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();"
What is this mapper? I tried to reproduce your example and it says to me that <Cannot resolve symbol 'mapper'>.
Again, thank you for your advices and help!

Comment: The Jackson ObjectMapper  (com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper) is the simplest way to parse JSON with Jackson. ObjectMapper can parse JSON from a string, stream or file, and create a Java object or object graph representing the parsed JSON. I've updated the code having the Object mapper defined.

Comment: Thank you so much, i will keep my studies with your example!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the paths, then build some kind of tree object in memory, and finally convert the tree that you built into JSON.

Here are some tips:

- Start by defining an empty root element. You can use a `Map`. Keys will be strings, values will be either strings, lists or maps.
- For each path, split it by "/".
- For each path element except the last, check if it is a list or a subtree. You can distinguish this by the presence of `[n]` at the end of the string.
- Create all intermediate nodes for the path except for the last one. Starting from root (which is a `Map`), add either a `List` or a `Map` for each element if it doesn't exist yet under that name. If it already exists, check that it is what you need it to be. In case of `List`, append the element. In case of `Map`, create a sub-entry.
- For the last path element, add it as a `String`.
- Repeat this for all paths to fill your tree.
- When you are finished, use a combination of recursion and `StringBuiders` to construct the output string. Alternatively, if you only used strings, maps and lists, you can also use a library such as Jackson to produce JSON.

Note that you don't have information about the length of the lists, so this conversion will not be reversible.

Comment: Thank you @jurez! Your steps will help me a lot!