# Create JSON from path using java

Tags: java, json, java-8, jsonpath, jsonpointer

I need to create a JSON from path. for e.g my paths and its values looks like below

```
root/departments[name=dept1]/employees[id=emp1]/firstName = firstName
root/departments[name=dept1]/employees[id=emp1]/lastName = lastName
root/departments[name=dept1]/employees[id=emp2]/firstName = firstName
root/departments[name=dept2]/employees[id=emp1]/firstName = firstName
```

from this i need to generate json which looks like this.

```
{
"root": {
    "departments": [
        {
            "name": "dept1",
            "employees": [
                {
                    "id": "emp1",
                    "firstName": "firstName",
                    "lastName": "lastName"
                },
                {
                    "id": "emp2",
                    "firstName": "firstName"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "dept2",
            "employees": [
                {
                    "id": "emp1",
                    "firstName": "firstName"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

When i checked into JsonPath and JsonPointers this kind of structure is not supported.

Comment: I think this is what are you looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53529755/8291949

Comment: In the above example JSON pointer works with array indexes, in the above case i am trying to find object from arrays based based on a field value.

Comment: It's not a direct answer to your effort. For me, the main takeaway of the linked answer was: There is no such feature, and you may have to build your own facility to make it happen.