# Creating JSON document object model (DOM) using JSON Path (JayWay) in Java

Tags: json, jsonpath, jayway

I want to create a JSON String for a Map of JSON Path as key and the value is the JSON value itself.

(It is somehow mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71547055/2792012) as a solution) but neither 2.7 nor 2.8 version of Jayway's published maven Central has `Option.CREATE_MISSING_PROPERTIES_ON_DEFINITE_PATH`

**My question is simple:**
`Map<String, String> jsonMap;`

Example Key String, Example Value
`Customer.Account.Number, 1234`
`Customer.Account.type, Checking`

Expected:
`{"Customer":{"Account":{"Number":1234, "type":"checking"}}}`

Appreciate any help in this regards.

Comment: Are you using this? https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: Trying it but it's complicated to build the Json Path based Json Document Object dynamically.