# How to build a JSON object from a jsonpath query string and values

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jsonpath

How can I convert a given jsonpath string and values to a JSON object in Node.js or TypeScript?

For reference, the problem is elaborately defined here: [Create JSON Object from various JSON Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66560805/create-json-object-from-various-json-path)

Given:

```
$.student.firstName = "Abc"
$.student.subject['physics'].mark=100
```

I want to build:

```
{
  "student":{
    "firstName": "Abc",
    "physics":{
      "mark":100
    }
  }
}
```

I have not tried in Node.js or TypeScript, but have tried in Java. What I can do is:

1. Tokenize the jsonpath query
2. For the tokens, build intricate structure using Map
3. Convert the Map to JSON object/string

Comment: "*I have not tried in Node.js or TypeScript, but have tried in Java.*" Do you _know_ how to program in JavaScript or TypeScript? Or just Java?

Comment: I have written a custom solution in java, by tokenising the jsonpath and evaluating it to get the resultant json object. But as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66560805/create-json-object-from-various-json-path there is a readymade library that does it, so was wondering is there any such solution available in node or typescript or will I have to replicate my earlier implementation here in node as well and also looking for some recommendations to implement it. I am new to JS/ Node/ TS and learning it, given a logic I can implement in these languages as well